# IntelliJ Play Framework Project Structure Libraries 100+ errors found a.s.o

Tags: playframework, intellij-idea

There are two things which are total productivity killers when working with IntelliJ and Play Framework (not sure if there are similar issues with other frameworks).
1. Every time I change to a new version of the Play Framework, libraries are not found anymore, although specified in Build.scala as appDependencies (e.g. Solr, SolrJ). But there are also problems with JUnit which should be already around in IntelliJ.
2. IntelliJ keeps old (and duplicate) references to libraries in previous versions and marks them as dead links. How can I get rid of all these (see screenshot)?

[image: duplicate library entries and broken references]

This seems to be a problem independent from a particular OS, as we (my colleagues too) experience this with Windows 8 and Apple OS X.

Does anyone experience similar problems and knows how to solve them?
Or is there any good way to do a profound cleanup?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the IDEA support just appends to the existing IntelliJ project. Delete the hidden directories .idea and .idea_modules and then re-generate intellij files from play.

Comment: Deleted the directories and reran play clean && play idea, still the same list in Project Settings :/

Comment: Strange, that usually has solved my problem. I can see in my current project the same kind of behaviour, I have one set of libraries for each time I have run 'play idea' since I last deleted the files but since it has been with the same version of play they arent dead links, just useless.